# How to implement mobile device management using react native?

Tags: android, react-native, mdm

I am developing an application for internal use that allows a mobile administrator to configure and install applications from a local repository, like a play store or apple store but for applications distributed locally.
This application has to allow an administrator to disable/enable some features of the phone also, like access to the phone settings.

I'm currently able to install and configure applications, but I don't know what npm package to use for the administration of the system settings, wherever I look they say that third party application can't mess around with the system settings unless the device is rooted.
There is an npm package that allows to change settings one by one, but can't disable the home button, disable interaction with the notification panel, nor disable access to the phone settings.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are writing for business owned devices or [kiosk mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices) if you need some active IT control, you'll probably need to [write your own DPC](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/build-dpc) and/or look into the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/dev-options).